# libstdc++.so.6:version GLIBCXX_3.4.15 not found required by compiz

Tags: grub2, kernel, firefox

I got this error:

```
/opt/quartus/linux/libstdc++.so.6:version GLIBCXX_3.4.15 not found required by compiz
```

I am also unable to work with apt-get.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to

- Compile **gcc-4.6.2** with `--prefix=/usr/local/gcc462/`
- Copy **libstdc++.so.6.0.16** to **/usr/lib64/**
- Create a new symlink **libstdc++.so.6** to **libstdc++.so.6.0.16**

  Or
- Download .deb from this [location](http://pkgs.org/download/libstdc++6)  and grab  **libstdc++.so.6.0.16** from the package. To unpack the package use command: `ar -x <package> && tar xvf data.tar.gz`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thnks for reply, my gcc version is 4.6.2.but when i type this command in my terminal   is strings /opt/quartus/linux/libstdc++.so.6/ grep | GLIBC, the output is GLIBCXX_3.4 to GLIBCXX is 3.4.9 only but gcc is 4.6.2.How to compile gcc-4.6.2 wit --prefix=/usr/local/gcc462.kindly tel me sir.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you with Calibre: please note that changing the default installed Calibre libstdc++.so.6 to the one in use by your system can be accomplished simply by:

```
root@localhost:~# cd /[path to calibre]/lib/
```

This next command is optional as a method of keeping the installed libstdc++.so.6 for trouble issues, if unnecessary to keep the file then delete it.

```
root@localhost:/[path to calibre]/lib/# mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.KEEP_so.6
```

Finally link the system's libstdc++.so into the Calibre libray directory.

```
root@localhost:/[path to calibre]/lib/# ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6 \
/libstdc++.so libstdc++.so.6
```

---

Note: this from my system using Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS x86_64 with current updates applied via `apt-get`.